# Convert output and split into smaller string

Tags: c#

I am using the code below to break the stream by character.
In Main() i want the output to be converted and splitted into smaller string. How this can be done?

For example: current string array shows strNum[0] = "123456789"
instead I want strNum[0] = 1 strNum[1] = 2 strNum[2] = 3 strNum[3] = 4 strNum[4] = 5 strNum[5] = 6 strNum[6] = 7 strNum[7] = 8 strNum[8] = 9

Please advise.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> ReadByChunk()

        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\file.txt")))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() != -1)
                { // while not at the end of the stream...
                    yield return ReadUntilNextDollarSign(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        public static IEnumerable<char> ReadUntilNextDollarSign(StreamReader reader)
        {
            char c;
            // while not at the end of the stream, and the next char is not a dollar sign...
            while (reader.Peek() != -1 && (c = (char)reader.Read()) != '$')
            {
                yield return c;
            }
        }
 static void Main()
        {
           foreach (IEnumerable<char> chars in ReadByChunk())
           {
                    char[] charNum = chars.ToArray();
                    string str = new string(charNum);
                    string[] strNum = new string[] { str };
                    //more code
           }
```

Comment: "current string array shows str[0] = "123456789" " but in your code the `str` is not an array. If you do `str[0]` it would return a `char` and this would be the first character in your string. What exactly is your problem here, that part is still unclear to me

Comment: you actually need only 1 line: `string[] strNum = chars.Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all, you're assigning the value `str` to `strNum`, which would assign the whole of `str` straight into index `0`.

I would just map your `char[]` array to `string[]` using

```
var strNum = charNum.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

or an even *simpler* 1 liner as pointed out by **@Mong Zhu**

```
string[] strNum = chars.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```